# Merging JSP code and Maven code

Tags: java, jsp, jira

I have an Apache Maven Project for `JIRA REST API`. Now I am creating a `JSP` project to send some data to java file in my Maven Project. I want to know how can I merge them in single project. Maven Project has a `pom.xml` file and the java file for Maven are located in `src/main/java` whereas for JSP it is in different folder. (`Java Resources/src`)

Can anyone please tell what folder should I copy and merge?

EDIT: Found the answer. Right click the Maven project and go to `Project Facets` and check `Dynamic Web Module` option.

Comment: An alternative to a single project would be to have the web project depend on the API project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Right click the Maven project and go to Project Facets and check Dynamic Web Module option.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Maven Webapp using following archetype

```
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

which will automatically creates the desired folder structure

in your case its apart from `src\main\java`

```
src\main\resources
src\main\webapp
src\main\webapp\WEB-INF --THIS IS WHERE JSP's will go
```

[Standard Maven Directory Layouts](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

[Maven Web Application](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_web_application.htm)